What does the OpenSSL error "SSL routines::bad record type" indicate?
While using OpenSSL's development library (<openssl/ssl.h>) sometimes, on new connections, I get the error

error:0A0001BB:SSL routines::bad record type

which is an SSL_ERROR_SSL with error code from ERR_get_error() 167772603. As far as I can tell, this happens when calling SSL_read for the first time in a connection.
I know that when an SSL_ERROR_SSL happens, the SSL object must be destroy, but I'm wondering how I can avoid this error or find more information on how to deal with certain OpenSSL errors, as I have basically looked everywhere and haven't found anything relating to what it means.

Can be a bug on the server site, can be a client trying to access a server with TLS but the server does not speak TLS, ... . Too much unknown about the cause of the error in your specific case in order to give recommendations on how to deal with it.

can you recreate this behaviour consistently when accessing specific addresses ? , provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of your code may help folks respond with relevant feedback, otherwise we're where @SteffenUllrich says.

@SteffenUllrich the server is my own, and its a WIP, hence why I needed help finding more info on the error

@ticktalk the address is always localhost, as I'm still testing the server. The code spans multiple files and usually happens when calling SSL_read (I'll edit my post to reflect that) but otherwise I think its too large to put here. Still, I'll see if I can do it and update my post accordingly

TLS records have different types associated with them, e.g. "handshake", "application data", "alert", etc. This error means that OpenSSL has received a record with a type that doesn't make sense for the context. It's quite an unusual error to occur, however I have seen this happen in TLSv1.3 which only uses "application data" for on the-wire records after the initial handshake is complete, e.g. if an application accidentally reuses a socket for a new handshake which is already being used for an existing connection, then this error can occur.
